# How to capture text from cmd while using cmd?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, output

Am using the built-in perl debugger of Activestate in Windows.

Now when I enter debug mode in `cmd` with the command `perl -d script.cgi`, I want to able to capture all the output from `cmd` to a file.

1. I am not able to use the `command >> output.txt` because I am in debug mode.
2. I don't want to use `command.bat >> output.txt` because I execute debug commands based on the output of `cmd` and it doesn't work when I am past the debug command.

Comment: Does Windows implement the `tee` command? That may solve your problem if it does. Alternatively you might be able to mess with the debugger's default filehandle.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the output & variable data everything, but for this you need to develop a wrapper script to print the outputs of each command.
On searching you will get many scripts for this purpose.

But I recommend to use editor/debugger like:

1. Eclipse with EPIC plugin (Free), OR
2. Komodo (** Paid)

And for capturing output to file, eclipse also supports console output to file option.